# separate two html forms

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms

I create a two forms here http://jsfiddle.net/B9r22/8/ and when you submit them, they convert to JSON, and the problem is when you submit the first form and then the second form, there are both data from form in JSON, how can I reset forms or seperate them?

```
<form name="first" id="1" action="" method="post">
Which city is in Great Britain?<br/>
London:<input type="radio" name="first" data-questionid="1" value="11"/><br/>
New York:<input type="radio" name="first" data-questionid="1" value="12"/><br/>
<p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>

<form name="second" id="2" action="" method="post">
Which city is in USA?<br/>
Washington:<input type="radio" name="second" data-questionid="2" value="13"/><br/>
Tokio:<input type="radio" name="second" data-questionid="2" value="14"/>
<p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the form as scope when you get the radio buttons:

```
$('input[type="radio"]:checked', this)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B9r22/11/

Comment: yes it works ... and I have another small problem, when there is a text http://jsfiddle.net/B9r22/13/ and when is not filling I want to have empty JSON, is there something like input[type="radio"]:checked for text

Comment: @user3357400: You can use the `filter` method to get only the inputs with content: `$('input[type="text"]', this).filter(function(i, e){ return $(e).val().length > 0; })`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form reset, this will set inputs to their default values, but ignores some fields like `type=hidden`

`$('#1')[0].reset();`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the problem lies in line 6. Your script collects data from all `input` fields in the whole DOM (document) with a type of radio. Instead, give the selector the context of the currently submitting form to only match those particular fields (using `$(this).find` where `$(this)` refers to the submitted form):

Change line 6 to `$(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){`

http://jsfiddle.net/B9r22/12/

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the

> $('input[type="radio"]:checked')

to the submitted form:

```
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var form = $(this);
        //....

        $('input[type="radio"]:checked', form).each(function(){
            //...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B9r22/9/

Answer (score 0):

you should use $(this)

```
$(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B9r22/10/